# Access. How can i change it if record is null?

Tags: ms-access

I have this table and this code

CAMPO10.      CAMPO12

1                      01012018

2                      01012018

1                      05012018

2                             -

1                      10012018

2                      10012018

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from MESERIFERIMENTO;"
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, 3, 3
Do While Not rs.EOF
If rs("Campo10") = 1 Then
campo4 = rs("Campo10")
campo5 = rs("Campo12")
End If
If rs("Campo10") = "2" And IsNull(rs.Fields("Campo12").Value) Then
MsgBox "Has nulls"
strSQL = "Update MESERIFERIMENTO SET [Campo12] ='" & campo5 & "' ;"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End If
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to change and what do you want to change it to? All records? Do you expect the records to be processed in a specific order? Please tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from MESERIFERIMENTO;"

rs.Open strSQL, cnn, 3, 3

Do While Not rs.EOF
    If rs("Campo10").Value = 1 Then
        campo5 = rs("Campo12")
    End If
    If rs("Campo10").Value = 2 And IsNull(rs.Fields("Campo12").Value) Then
        MsgBox "Has nulls"
        rs("Campo12").Value = campo5
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Comment: Yes.
but my code goes wrong!
and I do not understand why.

Monday I will try again.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK, but "goes wrong" isn't very useful. Be more explicit, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Nz function in your query to convert nulls to 0 if 0 is not excpected.

```
strSQL = "SELECT Campo10, Nz(Campo12,0) from MESERIFERIMENTO;"
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, 3, 3
Do While Not rs.EOF
  If rs("Campo10") = 1 Then
    campo4 = rs("Campo10")
    campo5 = rs("Campo12")
  End If
  If rs("Campo10") = "2" And rs("Campo12")=0 Then
    MsgBox "Has nulls"
    strSQL = "Update MESERIFERIMENTO SET [Campo12] ='" & campo5 & "' ;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
  End If
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Comment: thank you Allan, but your code gave me error. Thank you anyway